# How can the data (DML commands) be exported as a script from Oracle Apex 5

Tags: export, oracle-apex-5

I have been able to export application and tables (DDL) but couldn't export data that reside inside the tables i.e. the script doesn't consist of insert statement. I want to run that in another workspace.

Someone suggested to install ApexLib Schema Export Tool  as it exports everything with one click. But the problem is that i am using Oracle's web service of Apex and this tool can work only in the local Apex (Installed locally)

This is so strange that Oracle doesn't provide such a basic feature of exporting data script in Apex 5 and to do so, a tool must be installed.
Can Anyone suggest a better solution than this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems either no one is interested in answering the question or no one has knowledge of Oracle Apex 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to hook up your APEX instance to SQLDeveloper or toad and get the insert statements through there.  If you don't have access to those (i.e. are running your instance on apex.oracle.com) then you could use the data unload found at `SQL Workshop -> Utilities -> Data Unload`, then just create the table on the other side using your ddl and import the data back in.

Comment: It unloads the data in text or html format which cant be run as script in 'SQL Workshop -> SQL Script' . It consists of only data of the table's fields without INSERT commands @RLOG

Comment: You can use the data loader to load it back in.